# The "sticks" variable cannot be re-assigned to 0 in C++14

Tags: c++, algorithm, variables, c++14

I am writing a program to resolve the request:

> Count the number of match sticks used to create numbers in each test case
>
> [image]

Although it is a simple problem, the thing that makes me quite confusing is that the program has no error but the output is not as expected.

Source Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<char,int> digits={
    {'0',6},{'1',2},{'2',5},{'3',5},{'4',4},{'5',5},{'6',6},{'7',3},{'8',7},{'9',6}
    };
    map<char,int> peterMap;
    int t; cin >> t;
    string peterNum[t];
    for(string &a:peterNum) cin >> a;
    for(string b:peterNum){
        int sticks = 0;
        string tomNum, n;
        for(char c:b) ++peterMap[c];
        for(auto d:peterMap) sticks += d.second*digits[d.first];
        cout << sticks << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
5              (Number of test cases)
1 0 5 10 15
```

Output:

```
2 8 13 21 28
```

Expected Output:

```
2 6 5 8 7
```

Comment: `string peterNum[t];` is not standard C++.

Comment: *"the program has no error but the output is not as expected."* -- no, the output being not as expected **is** an error. You probably meant no error reported by the compiler (i.e. a syntax error), which is hardly a reason to expect no semantic errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code

- [don't use  `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), it is non-standard and promotes bad practice.
- [variable-length arrays are not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/), use `std::vector` instead. But this is actually not necessary in this case, because...
- `peterMap` is completely unnecessary and needs to be removed, it is screwing up your result.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<char,int> digits = {
        {'0',6},{'1',2},{'2',5},{'3',5},{'4',4},{'5',5},{'6',6},{'7',3},{'8',7},{'9',6}
    };
    int t; cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        string a; cin >> a;
        int sticks = 0;
        for(char ch : a) sticks += digits[ch];
        cout << sticks << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/c5lUxc)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
        for(char c:b) ++peterMap[c]; // <<--here
        for(auto d:peterMap) sticks += d.second*digits[d.first];
```

You are increasing number in map and use it in next statement without reseting for next input entry.

But there are several problems with your code:

1. Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. I hate hackerrank for using this in their solution template.
2. Using `string peterNum[t];` is not standard as mentioned in comments.
3. From my point of view, you don't need to use `std::map` for `peterMap` at least. Just iterate over characters of each string.